# Whenever I input bigger number first it doesn't print out anything

Tags: java

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1, num2;
    
        System.out.print("Enter 2 numbers");
        num1 = scan.nextInt();
        num2 = scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = num1; i <=num2; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "");
        }
    }
}
```

When I put the first number bigger than the second number, the program doesn't output anything; it is just blank.

Comment: `i` will be set to the first number and as the first number is bigger then the second number `i <= num2` will be `false`. The loop will be skipped.

Answer (score 4):

Your `for` loop sets `i` to be `num1` and then checks the condition `i <= num2`. If `num1` (and thus, `i`) is bigger than `num2` the condition evaluates to false, so the `for` body is never executed.

Comment: so what should i do sir?

Comment: You should somehow make sure that the case I described does never actually happen. How you do this and what your program does (if it should) to notify the user (or any caller) is design and thus entirely up to you.